# Loading local file into HDFS using hdfs put vs spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

Usecase is to load local file into HDFS. Below two are approaches to do the same , Please suggest which one is efficient.

Approach1: Using hdfs put command

```
hadoop fs -put /local/filepath/file.parquet   /user/table_nm/
```

Approach2: Using Spark .

```
spark.read.parquet("/local/filepath/file.parquet  ").createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
spark.sql(s"insert into table table_nm select * from temp")
```

**Note:**

1. Source File can be in any format
2. No transformations needed for file loading .
3. table_nm  is an hive external table pointing to /user/table_nm/

Comment: Txt file and parquet files differ in approach, hence not a valid question.

Comment: both are parquet files. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that they are already built local .parquet files, using -put will be faster as there is no overhead of starting the Spark App.

If there are many files, there is simply still less work to do via -put.